# Will hangouts phone call use data or cellular

Tags: google-hangouts

I am going on a roadtrip from Canada to the USA. I am purchasing a ATandT sim card that only allows for US calls and texts (at a reasonable price).

I want to use hangouts to call people, but have never used this feature. Does a hangout phone call use data just like video call does? Or will hangouts first check if this contact has a phone number associated with it, and instead use that.

Th reason I ask is because I don't want to be calling someone and assume I am using data, when infact it used cellular and I am paying $1 per minute.

Answer (score 1):

Being an online mobile app, Hangouts uses only data (your bandwidth) to make the calls, not your actual telephone line. As per [this Google support link](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3187125?hl=en), calls to most destinations in USA and Canada are free of cost from Hangouts so you shouldn't be billed anything (but you will be billed for the data/bandwidth used, of course!)

The exception is a few rare locations mentioned in that link that cost 1 cent per minute. And those calls will not be billed by AT&T, to pay for those calls, you'll have to purchase Google calling credit from [here](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3204856) separately.

Reference:

https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3187125?hl=en

> Or will hangouts first check if this contact has a phone number associated with it, and instead use that.

You can either dial a number directly, or if you have that person in your Google contact list, you just type the name and number will come automatically. Even if the person doesn't have a number, Hangouts will work and you'll be able to make the call since that contact's identity will be based on the Google account, not their telephone numbers (check the *Making a call with Hangouts* section in the referred link). Google is all about seamless communication!

**Edit**

But what I don't understand is why are you paying for both a data plan and  talktime to AT&T? As per the support link, US & Canada calling is mostly free from hangouts, so if you already have a data plan, I don't see any need to buy that sim card for "making calls at a reasonable price".